# Generating Account Balance In Access 2010

Tags: ms-access, database-design, vba, ms-access-2010

This is a higher level question, but it will likely spin into more as I hear back from the group.

I am looking for the best way to setup Access 2010 to keep track of my client account balances. We sent monthly invoices and they send up a check in return.  I've been scouring the exchange looking for an answer, but haven't quite figured it out yet.  Most say to set up a transaction table, but then how do you find the account balance and where do you put that so it can accessed when generating next months invoice?

My initial thought was to create a table with all the relevant client information; name, address, etc.  Then I will have a table for all my transactions; both in (check rec'd) and out (invoices).

I would set up a form from the transaction table to log the money received, then I would create another form to create invoices, which, upon saving, would log that amount to the transaction table.

It's hard to build something when you just get your mind wrapped around the entire thing.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Any information you want to store so you can retrieve later should go in a table somewhere. If you're doing balances, it may be better to do a calculated field on a form. A calculated field would not be bound to any field in your table(s), but rather it would use data from your tables in an expression that would calculate the balances while you had the form open.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense and that is the direction I am going.  I currently made a transactions table that will hold all the information I want to store.  Now I am working on a query that will sum up 'Credits' & 'Debits' per account. The expression I have written is - Total Debits: DSum("[Debit]","tblTransactions","ClientID =" & [ClientID]).  For some reason it's not getting formatted as currency like in the table, and when I run the query I can't sort that column because I get an error message: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression ('Total Debits').  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'd avoid using DSUM in this scenario. Use Totals -> SUM function in your query design and the currency should pull through. It's accessed in the query design view from the "Design" tab using the "Totals" button (Access 2013). Refer to the screenshot in this article: http://bit.ly/1IRcm5y ..if you replace the ProductName field with your ClientID field and set the total to "Group By" and then replace the UnitsInStock field with your Debit field and set the total to "Sum" you should get what you're after (hopefully it'll sort properly too).

Comment: That worked!  They were able to sum correctly and group under each account. I have now setup an expression that can the transaction table.